# Docker cannot copy to non-directory node_modules

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, node-modules

I'm using docker to deploy to a fly.io server.  The first three `FROM` commands were taken straight from the documentation.  I require a few JavaScript packages to be installed off of npm. In order to facilitate that, I added the `javascripts` build step, and tried to copy from this `javascripts` build step into my final image.

`Dockerfile`

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental

# Dockerfile used to build a deployable image for a Rails application.
# Adjust as required.
#
# Common adjustments you may need to make over time:
#  * Modify version numbers for Ruby, Bundler, and other products.
#  * Add library packages needed at build time for your gems, node modules.
#  * Add deployment packages needed by your application
#  * Add (often fake) secrets needed to compile your assets

#######################################################################

# Learn more about the chosen Ruby stack, Fullstaq Ruby, here:
#   https://github.com/evilmartians/fullstaq-ruby-docker.
#
# We recommend using the highest patch level for better security and
# performance.

ARG RUBY_VERSION=3.0.0
ARG VARIANT=jemalloc-slim
FROM quay.io/evl.ms/fullstaq-ruby:${RUBY_VERSION}-${VARIANT} as base

ARG BUNDLER_VERSION=2.2.3

ARG RAILS_ENV=production
ENV RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV}

ENV RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES true
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT true

ARG BUNDLE_WITHOUT=development:test
ARG BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle
ENV BUNDLE_PATH ${BUNDLE_PATH}
ENV BUNDLE_WITHOUT ${BUNDLE_WITHOUT}

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir -p tmp/pids

#######################################################################

# install packages only needed at build time

FROM base as build_deps

ARG BUILD_PACKAGES="git build-essential libpq-dev wget vim curl gzip xz-utils libsqlite3-dev shared-mime-info nodejs npm"
ENV BUILD_PACKAGES ${BUILD_PACKAGES}

RUN --mount=type=cache,id=dev-apt-cache,sharing=locked,target=/var/cache/apt \
    --mount=type=cache,id=dev-apt-lib,sharing=locked,target=/var/lib/apt \
    apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y ${BUILD_PACKAGES} \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives

#######################################################################

# install gems

FROM build_deps as gems
RUN apt-get install -y shared-mime-info

RUN gem update --system --no-document && \
    gem install -N bundler -v ${BUNDLER_VERSION}

COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN bundle install &&  rm -rf vendor/bundle/ruby/*/cache

#######################################################################

# install javascript deps

FROM build_deps as javscripts

RUN apt-get update -y -qq
RUN apt-get install -y curl software-properties-common
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - 
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs 

RUN mkdir -p /app/lib/javascript_runtime

WORKDIR /app/lib/javascript_runtime

COPY lib/javascript_runtime ./


RUN npm install npm@latest -g. --no-bin-links
RUN npm install --no-bin-links


#######################################################################

# install deployment packages

FROM base

ARG DEPLOY_PACKAGES="postgresql-client file vim curl gzip libsqlite3-0 nodejs shared-mime-info"
ENV DEPLOY_PACKAGES=${DEPLOY_PACKAGES}

RUN --mount=type=cache,id=prod-apt-cache,sharing=locked,target=/var/cache/apt \
    --mount=type=cache,id=prod-apt-lib,sharing=locked,target=/var/lib/apt \
    apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    ${DEPLOY_PACKAGES} \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives

# copy installed gems
RUN mkdir -p /app/lib/javascript_runtime/node_modules
COPY --from=gems /app /app
COPY --from=gems /usr/lib/fullstaq-ruby/versions /usr/lib/fullstaq-ruby/versions
COPY --from=gems /usr/local/bundle /usr/local/bundle
COPY --from=gems /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml 
COPY --from=javscripts /app/lib/javascript_runtime/node_modules /app/lib/javascript_runtime/node_modules
#######################################################################

# Deploy your application
COPY . .

# Adjust binstubs to run on Linux and set current working directory
RUN chmod +x /app/bin/* && \
    sed -i 's/ruby.exe/ruby/' /app/bin/* && \
    sed -i '/^#!/aDir.chdir File.expand_path("..", __dir__)' /app/bin/*

# The following enable assets to precompile on the build server.  Adjust
# as necessary.  If no combination works for you, see:
# https://fly.io/docs/rails/getting-started/existing/#access-to-environment-variables-at-build-time
ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE 1
# ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=1
# ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=1

# Run build task defined in lib/tasks/fly.rake
ARG BUILD_COMMAND="bin/rails fly:build"
RUN ${BUILD_COMMAND}

# Default server start instructions.  Generally Overridden by fly.toml.
ENV PORT 8080
ARG SERVER_COMMAND="bin/rails fly:server"
ENV SERVER_COMMAND ${SERVER_COMMAND}
CMD ${SERVER_COMMAND}
```

Everything before the COPY stage works fine, but fails upon copy (it fails upon copying a node_module dependency):

```
 => CACHED [stage-4  4/11] COPY --from=gems /app /app                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-4  5/11] COPY --from=gems /usr/lib/fullstaq-ruby/versions /usr/lib/fullstaq-ruby/versions                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-4  6/11] COPY --from=gems /usr/local/bundle /usr/local/bundle                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-4  7/11] COPY --from=gems /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml                                                    0.0s
 => [stage-4  8/11] COPY --from=javscripts /app/lib/javascript_runtime/node_modules /app/lib/javascript_runtime/node_modules                                                             0.6s
 => ERROR [stage-4  9/11] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                       0.5s
------
 > [stage-4  9/11] COPY . .:
------
Error: failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building: cannot copy to non-directory: /data/docker/overlay2/jueeknoajos61mik6hvgvrtli/merged/app/lib/javascript_runtime/node_modules/express
```

I've seen a lot of posts that demonstrate the same problem, but after trying lots of permutations I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arose because I had a locally checked out package referenced in my `package.json`.

Something like:

```js
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "express": "file:../../../express",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Updating this to a version allowed the image to build successfully.